# A function returning the string of

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

I'm getting setup in mongodb, was looking into using the greater than hash parameter and I get an error. However, when I use a hashrocket it works. Why is this?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'
require 'pry'
require 'win32ole'

db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("test")
x = db['text']

y = x.find({a: {$gt: 0}})
y.each {|y| puts y }
```

Data

```
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('51630eea5a8d7b8a8be738c0'), "a"=>1.0}
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('51632de8583be71698000001'), "a"=>1}
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('51632de8583be71698000002'), "a"=>1, "b"=>2}
```

The Error

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
```

for this line at the $gt: part
    y = x.find({a: {$gt: 0}})

This while

```
y = x.find({'b' =>  {'$gt' => 0}})
y.each {|y| puts y }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `$gt` is being interpreted as a reference to global variable `$gt`, not a symbol `:$gt`. And since you can't use colonized hash syntax with variables, it rightfully expects a hashrocket. The query should work with both string and symbol:

```
y = x.find({'b' =>  {'$gt' => 0}})
y = x.find({'b' =>  {:$gt => 0}})
```